# How to block multiple countries with one expression in google cloud armor?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

I can block multiple countries in google cloud armor with below rule.

origin.region_code == "RU" || origin.region_code == "UA"

But it considers this rule to be having 2 expressions so I can block only 5 couontries per rule and will have to add additional rules to block additional countries.

Is there a way (like in_origin_regioncode) where I can provide a comma separated list of all countries I want to block in a single expression?

Answer (score 10):

I have one option that we discover, you can use `x.contains(y)` function in your cloud armor rule, that function return true if substring y is in string x, so you can use it like this `'[CN,KP,LT,UA,RU,AF,DZ,MM,CU,EG,GN,IR,IQ,LR,LY,NE,SL,SO,SS,SD,SY,UA,YE]'.contains(origin.region_code)` instead of `origin.region_code=='CN'||origin.region_code=='SL'`  for example, and it works!!!

I hope I've helped
:)

Comment: FYI: just put `!` in front like`!'[CN,UA,BY,RU]'.contains(origin.region_code)` in front to deny this rule

Answer (score 3):

The best way that I found is using a regex, something like this:

`"origin.region_code.matches('^ES|PT|AD|GI$')"`

So you can include all countries as you want.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just want to allow ** CL REGION ** traffic, I created a permission rule in advanced mode. Traffic from other regions is blocked.

```
origin.region_code == 'CL'
```

Comment: In your case, the default rule must be set do deny, right?
Another option is to set the default rule as Allow and create this rule
**origin.region_code != 'CL'**

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly pointed out, and as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/armor/quotas), the currently custom rule limit is 5. The only workaround available to circumvent this is creating additional custom rules in order to implement additional country blocks.

Comment: That's a big oversight on Armor I believe. By comparison AWS WAF allows to put up to 50 countries in a rule.